# RMI server won't return class instances

Tags: java, jsp, rmi

I had a JSP/Servlet application that was running ok with MySQL. Now I had to implement the same application with RMI for my DAO's.

Through some tests I can see that it works fine when I return `int`, `String` or something like that. Remote methods with these type of objects works fine.

But when I try to call a remote method that returns an instance of a class I created (`Produto`) all the attributes of that object are `null`.

For example: I have a db table with 3 rows. The method returns a list with 3 objects on it, but if I call `product.getName()` for example I get this:

> null
>   null
>   null

On the following code, I'm not even using any database methods. Just a test method to see that an object `produto` will be returned with `null` attributes.

My interface, ProdutoDAO:

```
public interface ProdutoDAO extends Remote{ 
    public Produto teste() throws RemoteException;
}
```

My (what would be my Server) ProdutoDAOImpl:

```
public class ProdutoDAOImpl implements ProdutoDAO {

    private Connection con;
    Produto prod =  new Produto();

    public ProdutoDAOImpl() throws RemoteException {
        con = Conecta.getConnection();
    }

    public Produto teste(){
        prod.setNome("Testing! THIS WILL RETURN AS NULL");      
        return prod;        
    }




    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        int port = 1099;

        try {
            ProdutoDAOImpl obj = new ProdutoDAOImpl();
            ProdutoDAO stub = (ProdutoDAO) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            registry.bind("ProdutoDAO", stub);

            System.err.println("Server ready");

         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
         }       
     }
}
```

Index.jsp

```
Produto prod = new Produto();

try {
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(null);
    ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = (ProdutoDAO) registry.lookup("ProdutoDAO");
    prod = produtoDAO.teste();

    %><%= prod.getNome() %><%

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that `<%= prod.getNome() %>` is printing `null`.

Is it possible to return an object so I can read it's correct attributes?

Answer (score 1):

The class need either to implement Serializable or be an exported remote object. Yours is neither.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

Made my Produto class serializable and re-genrated the serial version on Eclipse.

```
public final class Produto implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 8367908553994431734L;
     ...

}
```